# Conditions for extending continuous function in euclidean space

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $X\subset Y \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and suppose $f: Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$.

Let $g =f\restriction_X$.

Is it true that if $g$ is continuous at $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{a}$ in the interior of $X$, then $f$ is continuous at $\mathbf{a}$? And if so, can we relax the assumption that $\mathbf{a}$ is in the interior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g$ and $f$ agree on a neighborhood of ${\bf a}$ and $g$ is continuous at ${\bf a}$, then so is $f$. That said, consider the following example with $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ and $g : [0,1] \to \Bbb{R}$ with $g = f|_{[0,1]}$ and

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0  & x \in [0,1]\\
-1 & x \not\in [0,1] \text{ and } x \text{ irrational}\\
1 & x \not\in [0,1] \text{ and } x \text{ rational}
\end{cases}
$$

Let ${\bf a} = 1$.

Comment: Or let $X=Y=[0,1]$ and $f=g = 0$ for $x \in (0,1]$ and $f(0)\neq 0$.